# Pre-commit Script for avoid commits biggers than 100MB

Tags: svn

I'm trying to build a pre-commit script which I can control the commits of the repository. I want to block all commits bigger than 100 MB. I was trying it with that code, but it doesn't work.

Commented are more options that I tried but didn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
#f="*/"
size=$(du -bshk $REPOS/db/transactions/$TXN.txn | cut -f 1)
#size=$(svnlook cat $REPOS -t $TXN | wc -c)
#size=$(svnlook filesize -t $TXN $REPOS $f)
if [ $size -gt 102400 ]; then  #250MB en bytes
        size=$(du -h -s $REPOS/db/transactions/$TXN.txn | cut -f 1)
        echo "Your changeset requires a disk space ($size) exceeding our 250MB limit">&2
        exit 1
else
        exit 0
fi
```

Comment: can't you use `#!/bin/bash` at the top? A real `#!/bin/sh` won't know what to do with `size=$(...)` , you'd need to use back-ticks instead. Did you run your code thru https://shellcheck.net ? Did you debug, using `set -vx` to see what commands are being executed and the values for variables that are being used? Good luck.

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://www.davidgrant.ca/limit_size_of_subversion_commits_with_this_hook

Comment: I tryed the code in shellcheck.net and no issues detected. Also I remove ·!bin/sh and still no works. I also tryed davidgrant script but it does not work for me.

Comment: I would like to try it with bash scripting. Any ideas about what can be happening? Maybe its about the way I get the size? Is there another way?